# Some trouble with 'php-mobile-detect' and if statement

Tags: php, mobile, if-statement

I'm using a small script called [php-mobile detect](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/) to be able to identify the device being used in order to make a download page more friendly.

I'm having some trouble with the code I'm using. When running this on a computer, the desired value is outputted, however, when accessing the code on a mobile device (The device I have at my disposal is an iPhone) I get a PHP error saying that `$deviceType` is undefined. I have a strong feeling I am doing something incorrectly in the `if` statement.

```
<?php
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
//Detect Platform
if($detect->isMobile()):

    if($detect->isPhone()):
        if($detect->isiPhone()):
            $deviceType = 'iPhone';
        elseif($detect->isAndroid()):
            $deviceType = 'Android Phone';
        elseif($detect->isWindowsPhoneOS()):
            $deviceType = 'Windows Phone';
        elseif($detect->isGenericPhone()):
            $deviceType = 'Phone';

    endif;//End if Phone

    elseif($detect->isTablet()):
        if($detect->isiPad()):
            $deviceType = 'iPad';
        elseif($detect->isAndroid()):
            $deviceType = 'Android Tablet';
        elseif($detect->isKindle()):
            $deviceType = 'Kindle';
        elseif($detect->isGenericTablet()):
            $deviceType = 'Tablet';
    endif;//End ifTablet

endif;//End ifMobile

//If not mobile it must be a computer
else:
    $deviceType = 'computer';
endif;// End Detect Platform

?>

<p>This is a <b><?php echo $deviceType; ?>
```

Any help will be most appreciated.

Regards,

Ian

Comment: Don't use the alternative syntax when you're not mixing php/html. It's ugly. You also don't have a default "unknown mobile device" in case all of those if() tests fail.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Even if I use the syntax with the `{}`, the outcome still doesn't change. Regarding the unknown mobile device - I thought using `isGenericPhone()` would solve the issue. However, I'm testing this on an iPhone so it should be recognized (that is if the code were working properly). Once again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$deviceType` is (obviously) not getting set when you use your iPhone. One way to get rid of the error is to declare `$deviceType` up at the top. This won't quite fix your problem though (your iPhone is still not being detected).

Looking at the docs for Mobile-Detect, I don't see `isPhone()` anywhere. Is this a real function?

--

(Probably) unrelated to your problem, but you may also want to add a generic `else` statement after each group of if/elses to catch any case that, for whatever reason, doesn't satisfy `isGenericPhone()` or `isGenericTablet()`. In fact, I would get rid of those and just use `else`.

By the way, alternative if/else syntax is annoying and makes code rather hard to read.

Comment: Yep! You're right - `isPhone` doesn't exist - I don't know where I got the idea from! Thanks...